# How to find track information and client_id for SoundCloud

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio, soundcloud

I'm trying to stream music from SoundCloud for an HTML5 player, and I want it to (at it's core) work exactly like this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kS97M/5/

```
SC.initialize({
  client_id: 'Enter your Client ID here'
});

SC.get("/tracks/81815566", {}, function(sound){
  $("#audio-test").attr("src", sound.stream_url + "?client_id=API_KEY");
});
```

That is someone else's client_id and track_id. I can't find anywhere to figure out how to get that information for my SoundCloud app. I created an app which gives me a client id, so I supposed that's fine, but how do I know why my tracks' streaming URLs are?

For testing purposes, the track I want to use is this https://soundcloud.com/coffitivity/morningmurmur and my client_id is 77ec4a0e70ef835e57efaf56677ea159

Answer (score 2):

You can review your apps and their client ids with the following URL: http://soundcloud.com/you/apps

You can get the track/playlist ids in various ways, but you will probably need to use [`/resolve`](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#resolve) endpoint of the API – you give it a regular URL for a track or playlist, or user and it returns the API representation with `id`s.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Resolve! Wonderful, thanks so much SoundCloud angel.